# I uninstalled xcode 4.6 and the App Store still wants to update it

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, xcode

A few months ago the app store notified me to update xcode. When I attempted to do this, the download hung and wouldn't complete. I tried several more times after restarting each time. Always the same result of hanging.

Today I was annoyed with the app store still bugging me to update xcode along with the amount of disk space xcode consumes so I tried to uninstall it. I removed xcode it from /Applications and any other references I could find and emptied the trash. I cleared caches, repaired permissions, and more, restarting both the computer and the application several times. I even enabled the debug menu and reset the application. Despite all of this, xcode still wants to update even though it no longer exists on disk.

I'm running mountain lion. I'm not sure if I had xcode 4.5 or 4.6 because it's all gone now (except the app store doesn't know it yet).

Comment: Did you reset the apple store?

Comment: Yes, I did. I mentioned it in the 2nd paragraph, "I even enabled the debug menu and reset the application."

Comment: Interesting, it still thinks you have the application :)

Comment: OK, did you clear the app store cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a backup, or external drive connected, that may have something of the Xcode install on it?

I know on my machine, if I have my backup drive connected the MAS thinks anything on that drive is currently installed.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you so much. I don't know when I would have finally put that together. I had no idea that App Store would look at an old installation stored on an external drive.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out after a fresh install of the OS and it still saw all of my programs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need Xcode any longer you can hide it under "Purchases" by right-clicking on Xcode and selecting "Hide Purchase".

Perhaps this works on the updatepage too. Can't check it as I don't have updates for the moment.

Your Appstore would still be broken but it shouldn't annoy you any longer if it works.